# ATG Repository - one to many mapping

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce

In our application, we have three tables `dps_user`, `account`, and `profile` for building user profile. The `profile` table has `account_id` as a foreign key. Based on this design, `userprofile.xml` is written. `account_id` is mapped as an `item-type` in xml which is working fine for one-to-one mapping. Every single account will have a separate profile.

Now we have a scenario one-to-many mapping (One profile associated to multiple accounts). We have a new table `profile_account` for this which has the mappings as below.

```
NEW_ID   ACC_NO   PROFILE_ID
======   ======   ==========
001      001      001
001      002      001
002      001      002
002      002      002
```

By default Account: 001 will be mapped to Profile: 001. Post-login we will get the `new_id`. With this value, we will fetch accounts and user will one of the accounts in the UI.

If user selects Account: 002 with `new_id`, then we have to update the profile with `ACC_ID`: 002. To achieve this, we retrieve the account item first and then update the corresponding profile item.

When doing this, we are getting below exception often and update is failing.

```
Error : java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock
```

Sometimes the update is successful in `profile` table but the old account is getting deleted from `account` table during this update. We have the cascade as insert,update,delete for account_id in profile table.

```
userProfile.xml:
<item-descriptor name="user" item-cache-size="3000" item-cache-timeout="900000" query-cache-size="1000" query-expire-timeout="900000">
    <table name="PROFILE" type="auxiliary" id-column-name="user_id">
        <property name="account" display-name="Account" column-name="ACCOUNT_ID" item-type="account" cascade="insert,update,delete" />
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
<item-descriptor name="account">
    <table name="ACCOUNT" type="primary" id-column-names="ID">
    <property name="accountNo" data-type="string" column-name="ACC_NO" />
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

Comment: Please post the parts of your `userprofile.xml` that represent the design you describe above. Will help in understanding your problem.

Comment: @radimpe: I have added userProfile.xml code. Pls check.

Comment: Where do you use the new table `profile_account`?

Comment: profile_account has not been linked with user item descriptor. We have a separate item descriptor for this. We just make a query to profile_account to get the profile id to update the account_id in profile table.

Comment: The issue you are seeing is probably related to the referential constraints in the database.  Oracle support has a [document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1493327.1) which describes the fix for this.